# Hibernate not creating tables with Maven and Spring-mvc

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, maven, spring-mvc

I have a simple project build with `maven2` and `Spring3MVC` running on TomCat 6. I want to have hibernate to create tables on runtime if they don't exist. However I had no success in it. Here are my files:

`hibernate.cfg.xml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory name="DKB">
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">dbk</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql:dbk</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">dbk</property>
    <property name="hibernate.default_catalog">dbk</property>
    <property name="hibernate.default_schema">dbk</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

`servlet-context.xml:`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources
mapping="/resources/**"
location="/resources/" />


<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property
    name="prefix"
    value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property
    name="suffix"
    value=".jsp" />
</bean>
<bean
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property
    name="persistenceUnitName"
    value="jtdb" />
    <property
    name="dataSource"
    ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property
            name="showSql"
            value="true" />
            <property
            name="generateDdl"
            value="true" />
            <property
            name="databasePlatform"
            value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
    <context:component-scan base-package="pl.spot.dkb" />
</beans>
```

and an example Entity Class:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Roles")
public class Role {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id_r")
    int    id_r;
    @Column(name = "name")
    String name;

    public int getId_r() {
        return id_r;
    }

    public void setId_r(int id_r) {
        this.id_r = id_r;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And part of `persistence.xml` with this class:

```
<persistence-unit name="Role">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>foo.bar.Role</class>
</persistence-unit>
```

Is there something I'm missing out?

**EDIT:**
Here's the TomCat log:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Projekty\SpringMVC\Tomcat6"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Projekty\SpringMVC\Tomcat6"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Projekty\SpringMVC\Tomcat6\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\jre\"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Projekty\SpringMVC\Tomcat6\bin\bootstrap.jar"
2013-03-05 11:19:23 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C
:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\jre\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;D:\app\K.Olejniczak\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin;D:\app
\K.Olejniczak\product\11.2.0\dbhome_2\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Progr
am Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DT
S\Binn\;"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\";"C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin";"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk
1.6.0_38\bin";C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;D:\app\K.Olejniczak\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\BIN;C:\Program Files (x86)\msls;C:\Program Files (x86)\Subv
ersion\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\gource;C:\Program Files\apache-ant-1.8.4\bin;D:\Research\PhoneGap\DevEnv\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\tools;C:\Program
 Files (x86)\ant\bin;D:\Research\PhoneGap\DevEnv\Cordova\android\bin;"C:\Program Files (x86)\Tail for Win32";"C:\Program Files (x86)\apache-maven-3.0.
4\bin";.
2013-03-05 11:19:23 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
2013-03-05 11:19:23 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 759 ms
2013-03-05 11:19:23 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
2013-03-05 11:19:23 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.36
2013-03-05 11:19:23 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor host-manager.xml
2013-03-05 11:19:23 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor manager.xml
2013-03-05 11:19:24 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive dbk.war
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Mar 05 11:19:25 CET
 2013]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root
-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.suppor
t.DefaultListableBeanFactory@41759d12: defining beans []; root of factory hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 324 ms
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'springServlet': initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'springServlet-servlet': star
tup date [Tue Mar 05 11:19:25 CET 2013]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spri
ngServlet/servlet-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for compone
nt scanning
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supporte
d for autowiring
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.suppor
t.DefaultListableBeanFactory@3d5b89c: defining beans [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0,org.springf
ramework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0,
org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#0,
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionRe
solver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springfra
mework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0,org.springframework.web.se
rvlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0,adminController,homeController,org.springf
ramework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.s
pringframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.spr
ingframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.Def
aultListableBeanFactory@41759d12
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/admin],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consu
mes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String foo.bar.admin.AdminController.adminHome(java.util.Locale,org.springframework.ui.Model)

INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[
],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String foo.bar.HomeController.home(java.util.Locale,org.springframework.ui.Model)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet
.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'springServlet': initialization completed in 8123 ms
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'adminServlet': initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'adminServlet-servlet': start
up date [Tue Mar 05 11:19:33 CET 2013]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spri
ngServlet/adminServlet-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for compone
nt scanning
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supporte
d for autowiring
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.suppor
t.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1b609c13: defining beans [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0,org.spring
framework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0
,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#0
,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionR
esolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springfr
amework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0,org.springframework.web.s
ervlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0,adminController,org.springframework.conte
xt.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework
.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.c
ontext.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBe
anFactory@41759d12
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/admin],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consu
mes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String foo.bar.admin.AdminController.adminHome(java.util.Locale,org.springframework.ui.Model)

INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet
.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'adminServlet': initialization completed in 190 ms
2013-03-05 11:19:33 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory docs
2013-03-05 11:19:33 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory examples
2013-03-05 11:19:33 org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory ROOT
2013-03-05 11:19:33 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
2013-03-05 11:19:33 org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
2013-03-05 11:19:33 org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/24  config=null
2013-03-05 11:19:34 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 10451 ms
```

Comment: Shouldn't <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">validate</property> this be set to update?

Answer (score 1):

In `hibernate.cfg.xml` you'll need to set `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` to `create`. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1689769/1276804) for more info on the possible values of that property and what they exactly mean.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

Comment: Nothing Nim. I tried all 4 of the proposed options from @zagyi's post, but not single one resulten in tables.

Comment: @Cornelius turn on logging, check the output, our connection is probably incorrect or user nto created. You also have to create the schema itself manually, hibernate will then create tables within the schema. Don't try all 4, to create tables you need create, or create-drop (whichs drops tables when undeployed).